# Issue with else statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below to retrieve row from the database, but if I enter id that doesn't exist in the database in 'assign_id_input', it won't execute the else statement and display out 'Error'.

```
$assign_id_input = $_POST['assign_id_input'];

$search_assign_user_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM free_ebook WHERE useid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error());

while($assign_user_id_array = mysql_fetch_array($search_assign_user_id, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $filtered_assign_user_id_array = array_filter($assign_user_id_array);

    if(count($filtered_assign_user_id_array) > 0) {
        echo 'No Error';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error';
    }
}
```

Comment: PLEASE indent your code.

Comment: Use var_dump() to check what your query is returning into the array, and enlightened you will be!

Comment: Surprised no-one raised a point about the injection and the library, so: please don't try and post-fix security, so from start don't do things as putting that `POST` variable straight into a query. It is untrusted data and could contain all sorts of stuff (like SQL commands). Furthermore, you use a deprecated library (mysql*). Check out the BIG red error on all manual pages about these functions (you did check the manual pages, did you?)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unindented, and slightly undreadable, but it appears to me that the problem is that you are assigning in the while loop. I think you should be using this.

```
while($assign_user_id_array == mysql_fetch_array($search_assign_user_id, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: That is not a problem. this is a way to fetch table rows. If mysql_fetch_array retuns FALSE the while loop will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't shown because your code never enters the while loop, because the
`$search_assign_user_id` has 0 rows in it, so `mysql_fetch_array()` will return `FALSE`.

You should check with `mysql_num_rows()` if your query returned any rows and after that you can enter your while loop.

```
$assign_id_input = $_POST['assign_id_input'];

$search_assign_user_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM free_ebook WHERE userid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($search_assign_user_id) > 0) {

    while($assign_user_id_array = mysql_fetch_array($search_assign_user_id, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $filtered_assign_user_id_array = array_filter($assign_user_id_array);
        echo 'No Error';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_affected_rows()` before your while loop

Comment: Please read the php manual. mysql_affected_rows() is deprecated and it only works on INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE not on SELECT. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: It is working for me in following manner  $sql = "Select * From abc";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or ("!sql");


if(mysql_affected_rows())
{
    echo "hi";
    
    
}

else
{
    echo "bye";
}

Comment: It may somewhow work, but the value returned by it is defenitely not the value you really want. And for future use, this function is depreacted and will get removed.